# How can I limit the maximum displayed items for a GTK4 Combobox and activate the scrollbar?

Tags: c++, combobox, scrollbar, gtk4

I am building a GTK4 app with a Combobox which contains 60+ items.
I can't find a way to limit the displayed items so that no scrollbar appears.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]